# Direct admin cron job, am I doing this right?

Tags: apache, cron

I am trying to load a cron job on my web-server. I want it to run a php script every 5mins. here is what I have

```
 */5    *   *   *   *   /usr/local/bin/php home/myusername/domains/servername.com/public_html/timecheck.php
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Depending on the result of the script it should send an email. If I run the script by the url it works fine.

Comment: Might need a `/` in front of `home/...`, depending on what user ID you're runnign this under .

Comment: it is on shared host, not sure what i would be running this as. Will give this a go tho

Comment: ok you got, please post an answer so i can give you the cred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might need a `/` in front of `home/...`, depending on what user ID you're running this under.

Comment: <<--- @maxum, there's a big honking green tick mark over there that you'll want to clicking on sometime after the next five minutes or so :-)

Answer (score 0):

*/5 should work, perhaps try 0-59/5

If that doesn't work, do it the hard way... 0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55

Comment: docs say "You can specify intervals using a star and a forward slash. eg: */2 (every 2nd minute)"